# What could cause slow binfmt-support.service during boot?

Tags: linux, boot, binfmt, slowdown

I have a Fujitsu LifeBook with Lubuntu 18.04.2 which is booting very slow. Here's the output from `systemd-analyze blame | head -n20`

```
28.869s systemd-journal-flush.service
24.957s dev-sda1.device
14.620s apparmor.service
14.558s systemd-udevd.service
14.161s binfmt-support.service
8.786s NetworkManager.service
8.366s udisks2.service
8.142s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
8.117s networkd-dispatcher.service
7.187s snapd.service
5.402s grub-common.service
4.975s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
4.383s ModemManager.service
4.028s accounts-daemon.service
3.988s gpu-manager.service
3.693s console-setup.service
3.343s keyboard-setup.service
3.203s apt-daily.service
2.780s apport.service
2.410s wpa_supplicant.service
```

I don't know what most of these are, but when I compare other users, I noticed most users don't seem to have binfmt-support.service at the top of their lists.

1. What might be causing binfmt-support to be slow at startup?
2. What can I do to make binfmt-support not take so long?